# Form Data Not Being Sent In ColdFusion

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I am trying to study ColdFusion (just starting out) and got stuck while doing some testing.

Basically, I am trying to pass data from form.cfm to storage.cfm. However, the data does not seem to get passed/sent.

Here is form.cfm (please ignore the markup, this is only for testing and I am absolutely new to CF so you might see something awful :D)

```
<cfparam name="userId" default=0/>
<cfparam name="firstName" default=""/>
<cfparam name="lastName" default=""/>
<cfparam name="address" default=""/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Learning CF</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Persons Table - <cfif userId EQ 0>Add<cfelse>Edit</cfif></h2>
  <form action="storage.cfm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="#userId#">
    <cfdump var="#userId#"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<cfoutput>#firstName#</cfoutput>"><br/><br/>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<cfoutput>#lastName#</cfoutput>"><br/><br/>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" value="<cfoutput>#address#</cfoutput>"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the cfdump here tells me userId is 0. Here is storage.cfm

```
<cfparam name="form.userId" default=""/>
<cfdump var="#form.userId#"/>
```

When I hit submit, what shows up in storage.cfm is only

**#userId#**

Comment: You need to enclose `userid` between `cfoutput`

Comment: Not related to your question, but much of the code in your form page looks unnecessary.  Specifically, it's anything to do with the set of variables at the top.  Also, having a cfoutput tag for every variable is inefficient.  If your form includes variables, wrap the entire form in a cfoutput block.

Comment: @Beginner why did you not make your comment an answer?

Comment: @DanBracuk Actually, the reason I have cfparams up top is because this also serves as a sort of an edit form. My plan was if the user clicks on "Edit" on a user on the previous page (code not in the question) it would have an href of say href="form.cfm?userId="#userId#"&firstName="#firstName#"&lastName="#lastName#"&address="#address#". Will that be a bad practice? If so, can I have a suggestion, please? Thank you so much for that heads up about those individual cfoutputs! By inefficient, did you mean in terms of performance?

Comment: @Beginner Thank you so much! That got the cfdump on the next page right!

Comment: About those cfparam tags etc, then you should scope them.  Sounds like the url scope would be appropriate.  This would make your code run faster because ColdFusion would not have to determine the scope for those variables.

Comment: @DanBracuk If I understood what I have read so far about scopes, I should just do something like <cfparam name="url.firstName" default=""/> and CF should interpret it as being in the URL scope, am I correct?

Comment: *Will that be a bad practice?* Yes. Normally "edit" links just pass an ID of the record to edit. The receiving page (ie form.cfm) then runs a database query to retrieve the other values (firstName, address, etcetera).  Since form.cfm only receives a single variable ie "userID", you only need one `<cfparam>`.  Though as Dan mentioned, the name should be scoped. Since the value is passed via a url, use `URL.userID`.  The other cfparam statements belong on the action page ie storage.cfm.  Though since your `<form>` uses method="POST", the values will be in the `FORM` scope.

Comment: @Leigh Aaahh yes why have I not thought about that?! Thank you so much for pointing that out! Appreciate it!

Comment: You might want to try [learn CF in a week](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/) site. It is very good for beginners. One bonus point by learning from this site is that at the end of the course you will have your own blog to publish built in CF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to enclose the `userid` between `cfoutput` so that it can be evaluated. Or better just wrap the form inside `cfoutput`.

```
<cfoutput>
  <form action="storage.cfm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="#userId#">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="#firstName#">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="#lastName#">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" value="#address#">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes perfect sense now!

Comment: *Or better just wrap the form inside cfoutput.*  .. which is far more readable than nesting individual tags inside each `input` :)